# Showing that g is a contraction in the ∞-norm, by using the p-norm

Tags: vector-spaces, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions, contraction-operator

My question is about, trying to show that the vector function $g = (g_1,\dots,g_n)$ is a contraction in the p-norm with $0 < L < n^{-1/p}$ and $1 \leq p < \infty$. After doing this, show that $g$ is a contraction in the infinity norm. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: Clearly more knowledge of the vector function $\mathbf g = (g_1,\ldots,g_n)$ in needed in order to show it is a contraction in either the $p$-norm or the $\infty$-norm.  See [this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to using mathematical notation on the site (it has links to more advanced information).

Comment: I've edited your question to format it using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/256128). The changes didn't take too much effort so it would be good if you could look at what I had to change by clicking on the "edited x ago" link above my name in the question to see what I did or read the guide I linked to so you could do this yourself in future